# Doing upload file via Jquery doesn't save temp file

Tags: javascript

I am implementing my own plugin for wordpress which has a field where to upload little files on server.

My piece is like:

**Html**

```
<div id="myFormDiv" class="my_editor">

    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="f_name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all f_name">
            <label for="f_icon">Icon:</label>
            <input type="file" name="f_icon" id="f_icon" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all f_icon">
            <label for="f_active">Active:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="f_active" id="f_active" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all f_active">

            <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
dialogForFile = $( "#myForm" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 480,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function(e) {   
                e.preventDefault();

                var itemf = {};
                var jsonData = [];

                ....

                jsonData.push(itemf);

                var dataElements = {
                    f_name: $("#f_name").val(),
                    f_icon: $("#f_icon").val().substr($("#f_icon").val().lastIndexOf("\\")+1),
                    f_active: ($('#f_active').prop('checked') ? "1" : "0"), 
                    file_icon: jQuery('#f_icon')[0].files[0],
                };

                var data = new FormData();
                for (var key in dataElements) {
                    data.append(key, dataElements[key]);
                    console.log(key, dataElements[key]);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://"+window.location.host+"/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.db.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    cache: false
                }).done(function (result) {
                        showListingMessage('Saved!');
                });

                dialogForFile.dialog( "close" );            

                //saveData("placements");
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                dialogForFile.dialog( "close" );
                showListingMessage('Not saved!');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            //allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }           
    });
```

**PHP**  myplugin.db.php

```
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $target_file_icon = UPLOAD_DIR . basename($_FILES["file_icon"]["name"]);

    $imageIconFileType = pathinfo($target_file_icon,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    switch ($_FILES['file_icon']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }

    if($imageIconFileType != "ico" && $imageIconFileType != "png" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only ICO & PNG files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_icon"]["tmp_name"], "./uploads/" . $_FILES["file_icon"]["name"]);
```

and the matter is once I submit I see in `$_FILES["file_icon"]["tmp_name"]` sort of `/tmp/php3iu23i2` which should be saved in php's temp file but looks like temp file isn't saved into `/tmp` so it couldn't move to destination folder.

I checked `php.ini` and it's OK. No errors sort of... just looks like it's doesn't really write file from source to `/tmp`

O.S. is Centos 5.8 Final and php version is 5.3.3

Maybe shall I have forgot something? Any trick would be appreciated

Thanks cheers!
Luigi

Comment: Are you really sure that the `"./uploads/" . $_FILES["file_icon"]["name"]` path is correct and writeable by your script? That the `chroot` and the `./`  match?

Comment: t.niese , that "./uploads" is like /var/www/html/uploads .... maybe shall I have to use the complete path ? and yes $_FILES["file_icon"]["name"] contains correctly 1-01.png which is a PNG file I am trying to upload

Comment: You should check what the result of `realpath('./uploads')` and `is_writable('./uploads')` right before the `move_uploaded_file` is.

Comment: I just tried to use complete path /var/www/html/uploads/ and it worked... I am surely a dumb haha oh well at least I solved inspiring from your suggest! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Personally I would never rely on `./`, but create a `static` or use `define`  to setup the value that contains `/var/www/html/` and use this as _root_. Something like `My_App::$basePath . 'uploads'`